# How do I make multiple lists from a file?

Tags: python, list, file

I am using this code to make labels in tkinter. After clicking on them, the text from **list1** changes to text form **list2**. I want to append the text into the lists from a txt file.

```
self.list1 = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("file.txt", encoding = "utf-8")]
self.list2 = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("file2.txt", encoding = "utf-8")]
```

Do I have to make for each list a single txt file? (How) can I make several lists from just one file?

Thanks

Comment: Cant really understand what you are asking.Are you trying to read from a txt file and then create a list and you want to read from the same txt file? Just use the same file.txt for evey list.

Comment: But how can I do that? When I use the code I wrote, it reads all the lines in the file. So it makes just one list.
Am I explaining it right?

Comment: so you want for example to read until it reaches a point, lets say it reads list2 and then it stops writing in list1 and writes in list2. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, it will read the file and let's say, that the first 5 lines will append to list1, the second 5 into list2 and the rest into list3. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def from_file_to_lists(name,lists): #Where lists[0] = list1, lists[1] = list2 etc
    i = 0
    for line in open(name, encoding = "utf-8"):
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if "line%s" % (i+1) in line: #if next list in line
            i +=1  #go to next list
            continue #dont write list name inside the list
        lists[i].append(line)
    return lists

#How to call
list0 = []
list1 = []
list2 = []
lists = [list0,list1,list2]
lists = from_file_to_lists("file.txt",lists)
```

Your file.txt should be like

```
Hello i
am list0
list1
Hello, i am
the second list
list2
i am the last
```

**Your list numbering inside the txt file should start from 0, else change**

```
if "line%s" % (i+1) in line:
```

to
    `if "line%s" % (i+2) in line:`

Comment: I think this is not what I meant. This code makes several lists, but all of them have the same inside. Right?

Comment: How can I put first 3 lines in the first list and the second 3 lines into the second one?

Comment: No they dont. First list has first 2 lines, second list has the 2 second lines, third list has the last line.

Comment: Maybe I just dont understand it. ‍♂️

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210496/discussion-between-jordan-and-daniel).